# iOS - Disable touch on UIImageView after it's been touched

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, tic-tac-toe, touch-event

I'm creating a Tic Tac Toe game in Xcode for the iPhone.

Everything works, I just want to disable touch events for each of the 9 squares once they have been touched, e.g. so users can't click the same square to change the value from X to 0.

I've tried `touch1.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` (`touch1` being the square `UIImageView` I want to disable) but no joy.

Any ideas?

Comment: Using UIbuttons? try `[touch1 setEnabled:NO]`

Comment: In order to answer the question we'd need to know how you're handling the touch events. What are you using? (e.g. UIButtons? Gesture Recognizers?)

Comment: @Mattia Reading the question again, I think he is using UIImageView, but he needs to show the code which shows how he handled his touches.

Comment: Is your gesture recognizer on the imageView or the imageView's superView? Disabling user interaction on the imageView only works if its the touch handler. If you're using a single gesture on the superview and doing math to find the touched view, you'll need to manage the disabled touch there.

Comment: //touch event for the game

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];
    
    
    //check to see which square was touched
    
    if(CGRectContainsPoint([_touch1 frame], [touch locationInView:self.view])){
        if(token == 1){_touch1.image = one;}
        if(token == 2){_touch1.image = zero;}
        
    }
    

}

Comment: That's the code for the touch events. There's 9 IF statements, one for each square

Answer (score 0):

I would make them all UIButtons instead of UIImageViews and set them all to send UIControlEventTouchUpInside to the same method. Then you distinguish which button was pressed by the sender parameter sent to your IBAction method and keep a track of which button has already been tapped in your game logic or in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You should set userInteractionEnabled property of UIImageView to NO after clicking on it

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: OP said he tried that and that had no effect (probably because he's not handling the touch event through the image view)